# How to analysis a data with both continuous and discontinuous characteristics

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Here is the data.
when the numeric variable is below 100, I can get its accurate number but when it is above 100, I can only group them into >100, >200 and >300. The explaining variable is discontious variable with 2 groups only.
how can I analyse this kind of data as the data exhibit both continuous characteristics and discontinuous characteristics? Should I set dummies for each group of numeric variables like when it is 1 to 99 then dummies = 1, when it is 100 to 199 then dummies = 2 and so on to do a statistical test?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to say when you “analyze” the data?

Comment: I want to find is there any difference between the 2 groups. thank you!

Comment: What kind of difference?